# preimages of simple functions form a partition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\varphi $ ba simple, then we know $A_i = \varphi^{-1} (a_i) $ . Claim is $A_i$ paritition $\mathbb{R}$

my try:

Note that the sets $A_i = \varphi^{-1} ( \{ a_i \} ) $ form a partition of $\mathbb{R}$. To see this, we show $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint. Suppose that there exists $x \in A_i \cap A_j $ and $i \neq j$. Therefore, we have that $\varphi(x) = a_i = a_j \implies 1_{A_i} = 1_{A_j} $. Hence, by Definition of the indicator function, we must have that $A_i = A_j$. Therefore, $A_i$ are parwise disjoint. In particular $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{N} A_i $.

Question; Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, this can be generalized as follows. Given any non-empty sets $X,Y$ and any function $f:X\to Y,$ letting $Z=f(X)$, we have that $$\bigl\{f^{-1}(\{z\}):z\in Z\bigr\}$$ partitions $X$.

It is immediate by definition of $Z$ that $f^{-1}(\{z\})$ is a non-empty subset of $X$ for each $z\in Z$. Supposing that $x\in f^{-1}(\{z_1\})\cap f^{-1}(\{z_2\})$ for some $z_1,z_2\in Z,$ we use the fact that $$f^{-1}(\{z_1\})\cap f^{-1}(\{z_2\})=f^{-1}(\{z_1\}\cap\{z_2\}),$$ so that $f(x)\in\{z_1\}\cap\{z_2\},$ so $\{z_1\}\cap\{z_2\}\ne\emptyset,$ and so $z_1=z_2.$ Hence, the sets $f^{-1}(\{z\})$ are pairwise disjoint.

Note that this is essentially the same as your approach.

Comment: that was beautiful.